# WooCommerce REST API: updating product variation attributes sets attribute name and option to Any:Any

Tags: attributes, woocommerce-rest-api, product-variations

So, I am making use of the endpoint https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?javascript#update-a-product-variation
to update existing attributes of a variation. The attributes have been added in the product before using them for variation. But, updating the existing attribute to the values available is setting them to Any:Any (which means attributes have been overridden with an empty array) and on the webshop the product now can be purchased in any combination of the attributes.

For ex.-
Existing attributes on the product variation were:

```
[{"name":"Brand", "options": "Bare Denim"},{"name":"Material", "options": "Cotton"}]
```

and updating the attributes to one of the available options from **Brand** and **Material**:

```
[{"name":"Brand", "options": "Levis"},{"name":"Material", "options": "Polyester"}]
```

is making the variation attributes set to an empty array. Variation attributes after update:

```
[]
```

Is this the right way of updating product variation attributes? Can the attributes be updated this way or will have to create a new variation in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of debugging and looking for the solution to this issue, I found it was a silly mistake of mine which occurred from giving **options** with variation attributes instead of **option**. Basically, while creating/updating product attributes *name* and *options* are used and in creating/updating variation attributes *name* and *option* are to be passed.

To all the ones, facing the issue with creating or updating product variation attributes please check once if these two keys are passed correctly or not. The major issues will be solved here only.

Answer to the questions I asked above:

> Is this the right way of updating product variation attributes?

It is the right way, but with a correction. Correct request data for variation attributes (notice it is **option** not **options**):

```
[{"name":"Brand", "option": "Levis"},{"name":"Material", "option": "Polyester"}]
```

> Can the attributes be updated this way or will have to create a new variation in this case?

Existing variation attributes can be updated using this and we can create new ones if required.

References:

- https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?javascript#product-variation-properties

Comment: when I update a product and change one of the attributes it erases all the products attributes and doesn't set the new ones.